# How to execute a MySQL stored procedure or function in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I made a Stored Procedure with MySQLWorkbench and tested it on that platform. The Stored Procedure runs fine on MySQLWorkbench but if I run the Stored Procedure with Flask-SQLAlchemy, I don't get any error but I don't see the results in the table.

I have tried the following ways of executing a stored procedure:

```
db.engine.execute("CALL stored_procedure_name(%s, %s)", (parm_1, parm_2))
```

This results in no error, but the function doesn't give the same results (in the database) as if i run the same function (with the same parameters) as in MySQLWorkbench.

I also tried:

```
db.engine.execute(func.stored_procedure_name(parm_1, parm_2))
```

It returned that stored_procedure_name was not a function, so I also created a function that was (almost) identical to the stored procedure, and run it using the same code, but it still doesn't run the function properly and does not return an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some reading of the documentation I found the answer. I still want to keep the question, because I think it is useful for some people.

You can run a function (so **not a stored procedure**) with the following code

```
db.engine.execute(text("SELECT function_name(:parm_1, :parm_2)").execution_options(autocommit=True), :parm_1 = :parm_1, :parm_2 = :parm_2)
```